# Too many bind arguments. 5 arguments were provided but the statement needs 3 arguments

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

when I try to update a row in my database , it says that only 3 arguments are needed but you have 5. I do not really know why is this happening because I am giving it 3 arguments. this is my codes:

```
 public void editdata(int id,String name,String Phonenumber){
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase=this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COLIMN_NAME,name);
        cv.put(COLUMN_PHONENUMBER,Phonenumber);
        sqLiteDatabase.update(TB_NAME,cv,"id=?",new String[id]);
    }
```

and this my alert dialogue:

```
 holder.btn_edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
                View add_view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_addcontacts,null);
               AlertDialog alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
                alertDialog.setView(add_view);
                final TextInputEditText edt_name=add_view.findViewById(R.id.edt_name);
                final TextInputEditText edt_phonenumber=add_view.findViewById(R.id.edt_number);
                Button btn_add=add_view.findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
                btn_add.setText("change");
                edt_name.setText(phonebookModel.getName());
                edt_phonenumber.setText(phonebookModel.getPhonenumber());
                btn_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        if (!edt_name.getText().toString().isEmpty()&&!edt_phonenumber.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                            phoneBookDB.editdata(phonebookModel.getId(),edt_name.getText().toString(), edt_phonenumber.getText().toString());
                            ((Activity)context).finish();
                            context.startActivity(((Activity) context).getIntent());
                        }else {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "please fill in the requested fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last argument of the method `update()` must be an array of non `null` strings, as many as the `?` placeholders:

```
sqLiteDatabase.update(TB_NAME,cv,"id=?",new String {String.valueOf(id)});
```

I guess in your code you pass `5` for the id and what you get with:

```
new String[id]
```

is an array of 5 `null` strings.

Comment: Technically, `new String[id]` was an array of strings. Sure, they are all `null`, and there are `id` number of them, but still ... --- Error message would indicate that `id` was `5`.

Comment: Yes an array of null strings.

Comment: But your answer argues that it "must be an array of strings", and the type passed to `update()` was a string array. All I'm saying is that you should clarify the wording of the answer, e.g. "must be a string array with length equal to number of `?` markers", or something like that.

Comment: The values of the string array are allowed to be `null`, so saying "must be non null" is wrong.

Comment: The argument of the where clause is `id=?` and it will fail if the passed value is null.

Comment: yes I got it, I think I was blind that i did not see that, thank you

Comment: @forpas Because where clause is `id=?` the query will return no rows if the passed value is null, but the statement won't *fail* (error out). It is *valid* for an argument to be null, because the where clause might be e.g. `id IS ?`. The `IS` operator works like the `=` operator, except that `NULL IS NULL` is true.

Comment: Although I never tried to pass null to a ? placeholder, are you sure that it won't be compiled as `id = 'null'`?

Comment: @forpas `null` and `"null"` are not the same, so why would it? And it would preclude where clauses like `id IS ?`, so that makes no sense.

Comment: I did not say that null is the same as 'null'. I asked if you are sure that the ? placeholder will not be replaced with a value like 'null', because I never tried it. In any case `=` will fail with a null parameter.